# Block part of a request using WAF or ModSecurity

Tags: mod-security, azure-waf

Is it possible to block just part of a request using ModSecurity, Azure WAF or similar? For example could you block a cookie because it contains invalid characters while allowing the rest through

I'm trying to trace an issue where sometimes a cookie is lost

Answer (score 0):

ModSecurity or the web server could possibly be used to drop cookies, the easiest way to troubleshoot will be to use an application proxy like BurpSuite and see what's going on with the cookie, often the browser is the one taking the decision to use or not the cookie.